# I want to replace all the vowels with z in string

Tags: c++, string

This code is replacing all the characters. Not just vowels. What am I doing wrong?

```
using namespace std;

bool isVowel(char);

int main() {
    string fName = "";
    string lName = "";
    cout << "Enter first name: " << endl;
    cin >> fName;
    cout << "Enter last name: " << endl;
    cin >> lName;
    string name = fName + " " + lName;

    cout << name << endl;

    for(int i = 0; i < name.length(); i++) {
        if(isVowel(name.at(i))) {
            name[i] = 'z';
        }
    }

    cout << name << endl;
}

bool isVowel(char c) {
    if(c == 'a' || 'e' || 'i' || 'o' || 'u' || 'A' || 'O' || 'E' || 'I' || 'U') {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I did some research online and I think my problem lies in that I am passing the character as a reference? I didn't understand how that could be...

The isVowel() function checks if the char is a vowel I think that's where the problem lies, since the program is replacing all the characters I'm assuming that function is not working.

Comment: The condition `c == 'a' || 'e'` doesn't do what you think it does. This condition is always true.

Comment: Clang warns about this with `-Wunreachable-code` turned on.

Comment: why is it always true? Isn't it checking is c is one of the characters listed?

Comment: "why is it always true?" `'e'` is true `'i'` is true `'o'` is true....

Comment: So is it treating `'e'` as: `if( 'e' ) { ... }` and `'e'` is just `'e'` and it thinks its true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to put your if statement as `(c == 'a' || c == 'e' || c == 'i'...`, the way it is written currently it casts all of the characters on their own as boolean expressions.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm new to c++ and I was trying challenges from the www.cplusplus.com forums but what does "the way it is written currently it casts all of the characters on their own as boolean expressions." mean? Edit: your suggestion solved my problem but I was just wondering what's wrong with my code...

Comment: So, when you run an if statement, the computer converts whatever is being checked into a boolean value (true or false).  This works similarly to boolean operators, the statement (x || y) expects x and y to be booleans, and converts them into booleans if they are not already.  In your code, `'e'` is in a place a boolean is expected, so it is converted to a boolean.  I'm not familiar with how c++ specifically handles this, but my guess would be that any non-null character is converted to true,

Comment: Correct, but there's no cast involved. Back in the good ol' days of C programming there was no `bool` type and anything that wasn't 0 was true. C++ adopted this behaviour.

Comment: It **converts** all of the characters. There are no **casts** in this code. A cast is something you write in your code to tell the compiler to do a conversion.